# WsHttpBinding VS WS2007HttpBinding VS WSDualHttpBinding..?

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding

Can any one tell me which type of wcf binding is useful for E-Commerce Application.

Answer (score 0):

Any of those bindings could be used for a service. Which binding you choose depends not upon the type of business, but upon the desired functionality.